# LINQ Intersect not returning items

Tags: c#, linq

I have implemented a comparison class for my custom class, so that I can use `Intersect` on two lists (`StudentList1` and `StudentList2`). However, when I run the following code, I don't get any results.

**Student:**

```
class CompareStudent : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
    {
        if (x.Age == y.Age && x.StudentName.ToLower() == y.StudentName.ToLower())
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Student obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class Student
{
    public int StudentId{set;get;}
    public string StudentName{set;get;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
}
```

**Main:**

```
IList<Student> StudentList1 = new List<Student>{
                new Student{StudentId=1,StudentName="faisal",Age=29,StandardId=1},
                new Student{StudentId=2,StudentName="qais",Age=19,StandardId=2},
                new Student{StudentId=3,StudentName="ali",Age=19}
            };
IList<Student> StudentList2 = new List<Student>{
                new Student{StudentId=1,StudentName="faisal",Age=29,StandardId=1},
                new Student{StudentId=2,StudentName="qais",Age=19,StandardId=2},

            };

var NewStdList = StudentList1.Intersect(StudentList2, new CompareStudent());

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is within your `GetHashCode()` method, change it to:

```
public int GetHashCode(Student obj)
{
    return obj.StudentId ^ obj.Age ^ obj.StandardId ^ obj.StudentName.Length;
}
```

In your current code, `Equals` is not called as the current `GetHashCode()` returns two different integers, so no point in calling `Equals`.

If `GetHashCode` of the first object is different than the second, the objects are not equal, if the result is the same, `Equals` is being called.

The `GetHashCode` I've written above is not ultimate, see [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) for more details on how to implement `GetHashCode`.

`GetHashCode()` [is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4340318/1361084) (and cannot be) collision free, which is why the Equals method is required in the first place.

Comment: I like (and use) this implementation from the thread you linked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18613926/3191599

Comment: Hi, Ofiris. First of all thanks for the solution. I have also tried Contains with particular ComparStudent class and returning the GetHashCode() of obj but it runs fine with particular statement. Do i need to use the particular solution for Conatns aswell or it behaves different in current scenerio.  Student std = new Student { StudentName="faisal",Age=29};    bool result3 = StudentList.Contains(std,new CompareStudent());

Comment: Yes, same answer is relevant for `Contains`:

`StudentList2.Contains(new Student{StudentId=2,StudentName="qais",Age=19,StandardId=2}, new CompareStudent()) //true`

Comment: Concerning the use of XOR (`^`) to compute a hash code from a composite value, see Eric Lippert's blog article [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx): _"'xor' can create or exacerbate distribution problems when there is redundancy in data structures."_

Comment: @Ofiris actually im trying to ask Why the previous CompareStudent class pointed in question works well with compare?

Comment: If this answer solves your original question, mark it as answer and if you have any additional questions, you can post them in separately.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `GetHashCode()` on the base object, which will return a different value for the different references.  I would implement it like this:

```
    public override int GetHashCode(Student obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return obj.StudentName.GetHashCode() + obj.Age.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. But given that there is a `StudentId` property, which supposedly uniquely identifies a student, why not use just that (instead of `StudentName` and `Age`) to compute the hash? `return obj.StudentId.GetHashCode();` (without `unchecked`) should suffice.

Comment: The original question did not use the student id in the equals implementation, so I assumed that they did not intend to use it for equality.